# CodeIgniter Parameter in middle of route

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm currently learning codeigniter but I'm having a bit of an issue with routing. My routes file is as below:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

$route['images/(:num)/upload/'] = 'image/upload/$1';
$route['images/(:num)'] = 'image/index/$1';

$route['yoyo/(:num)'] = 'yoyo/view/$1';

$route['default_controller'] = 'yoyo';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

My issue is with the first route; I'm unable to get it to work without moving (:num) to the end of the route. Based on other routes I've seen after browsing stackoverflow it get the impression that this should work. Any ideas?

So just to be clear it works if I add the follow route instead:

```
$route['images/upload/(:num)/'] = 'image/upload/$1';
```

Comment: You should keep reserved routes at higher places. Check the last quote from [docs](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html#reserved-routes) (marked in red): "The reserved routes must come before any wildcard or regular expression routes.".

Comment: Good point. Hadn't spotted that; I'll bear it in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$route['images/(:num)/upload/'] = 'image/$1/upload';
```

---

**Edit**: What was I thinking..sorry.

Of course you can't do the code I told you, because the route `images/$1/upload` means that you will access the controller `images` ...and the function `$1`.

Obviously, you can't do that. This is what you should do:

```
$route['images/upload/(:num)'] = 'image/upload/$1'; 


public class image extends CI_Controller
{
   public function upload($arg0) {}
}
```

And then if you want to pass more args, you just need to continue the route path.

```
$route['images/upload/(:num)/(:any)'] = 'image/upload/$1/$2'; 

public function upload($arg0, $arg1) {}
```

Comment: I've tried as this: 
$route['images/(:num)/upload/'] = 'image/$1/upload';
and unfortunately I'm still getting a 404.

Comment: Right, that's the state I had gotten working. I was just hoping I'd be able to have the parameter be in the middle of the route due to some hacky code I'd got in my constructor checking segment 2 of the URL.

Comment: @Linesofcode is it possible to add args in the middle of the URL like $route['images/(:num)/upload/'] = 'image/$1/upload'; ?

Comment: @BuddhimalGunasekara This is an old question, but taking in consideration what I have written, it seems no. You must put your args in the end of your route.

Comment: @Linesofcode $route['images/(:num)/upload/'] = 'image/upload/$1'; this is working fine now. thanx for your help